# Twisting a graph layout (by fixing the $x$ coordinate of all its vertices)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I would like to draw a given graph $G$ in a specific way and I would like to know whether *Mathematica* can do it in a (semi-)automated way.

My goal is to draw the graph $G$ in 2D, fixing all the $x$ coordinates of its vertices and letting the $y$ coordinates be arranged as they would be arranged by already existing layouts such as `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"` or `"SpringEmbedding"` (taking obviously in account the already fixed $x$ coordinates).

Q1) Is there a way to do this in *Mathematica*, possibly using one of the sub-options of `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"` or `"SpringEmbedding"` (e.g. `"EnergyControl"`)?

Q2) If the answer to the first question is negative, how would one build a function that, given the graph $G$ and the $x$ coordinates of its vertices, computes the $y$ coordinates to obtain such force-directed layout?

Comment: The other way around is possiblel (letting Mma set a layout and the re-setting the x coordinate), I think . However, if you want to first set the x coordinates I doubt you can get Mma to recalculate the ys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GraphLayout` to arrange your Vertexes by `SpringEmbedding` or other function, then extract the full two-dimensional locations of the vertexes, then assign the x-coordinate of each vertex to your known or desired x coordinates and re-display the graph with these new vertex locations.

```
 g = CompleteGraph[20, GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"];
```

[image: Basic complete graph]

```
myVertexCoordinates = VertexCoordinates /. 
 AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates][[1]];

myFixedXCoordinates = Table[RandomReal[],
 {Length[myVertexCoordinates]}];

myNewVertexCoordinates =  Table[
 {myFixedXCoordinates[[i]],
  myVertexCoordinates[[i, 2]]}, 
  {i, Length[myFixedXCoordinates]}];

Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> myNewVertexCoordinates]
```

[image: Simple complete graph with fixed coordinates]